# connect to linux nginx server from windows machine

Tags: 16.04, networking, windows-7

I've set a nginx server on my linux machine with IP 192.168.1.9 and i want to open it on my windows7 laptop. When i type https://192.168.1.9 in laptop's browser, it never connects. Note that ping works perfect and that i have no problem to open nginx server from my linux machine.

Comment: Does the server understand https? Maybe try plain http.

Comment: Yes, it understands. I'm running node.js  with nginx as a reverse proxy server. As i mentioned, it works fluently on linux machine with ssl encryption

Answer (score 0):

That is going to happen when you are newbie in Linux.It was simple...deactivating linux firewall.

```
   sudo ufw disable
```